Pipeline DevOps can't copy a nuget package
I'm trying to create a pipeline so that I can build my project directly on a server.
Here is my pipeline:
trigger:
- main

pool:
  name: XXXXX # name of local pool
  demands:
    - agent.name -equals XXXXX
  environment: 
    name: test_env

resources:
- repo: self

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'
    feedsToUse: 'select'
    includeNuGetOrg: true

- task: DeleteFiles@1
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
    Contents: '**/bin/**\n**/obj/**'
    removeSourceFolder: false

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)" /p:CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies=true'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

When I execute my pipeline, everything is fine up to VSBuild@1. However, at this stage, an error occurs:
Error : Copying file bin\System.Runtime.dll to obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\System.Runtime.dll failed. Could not find file 'bin\System.Runtime.dll'.

I looked in my files on my server to see if this dll was present somewhere, and when I restored it, the package in question was found in the ‘s/packages’ folder.
I also noticed that when running VSBuild@1, the ddl located in the s/packages folder is not copied to the project bin:
Copying file from "XXXX\3\s\packages\System.Numerics.Vectors.4.5.0\lib\net46\System.Numerics.Vectors.dll" to "XXXX\3\s\XXXX\bin\System.Numerics.Vectors.dll".
  Copying file from "XXXX\3\s\packages\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.6.0.0\lib\net461\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll" to "XXXX\3\s\XXXX\bin\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll".

